# th:with what is the difference between the two examples

Tags: thymeleaf

```
<p th:with="firstName1='James1'">
        <p>Upper</p><p th:text="${firstName1}"></p>
</p>

<p th:with="df='today'">
        Today is: <span th:text="${df}">13 February 2011</span>
```

[image]

Could you tell me what is the difference between the two code sections. They seem identical for me. But there is some difference as the results differ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I've never encountered this before... but it looks like Thymeleaf is enforcing the rule that `Any <p> (or other block-level element) will implicitly close any open <p>.` This works, for example:

```
<div th:with="firstName1='James1'">
  <p>Upper</p>
  <p th:text="${firstName1}"></p>
</div>

<p th:with="df='today'">
  Today is: <span th:text="${df}">13 February 2011</span>
</p>
```

In your example, the `firstName1` variable is out of scope because the parser is treating your HTML like this (so `firstName1` is considered `null`):

```
<p th:with="firstName1='James1'"></p>
<p>Upper</p>
<p th:text="${firstName1}"></p>
```

Comment: Well, I don't think so. For example, this is not woking: <p th:with="firstName1='James1'"> <p>Upper</p> <p th:text="${firstName1}"></p> </p> This is your example, but with a p. The problem seems to have something with blocks inside inline tags.

Comment: I just said if you use a `<p>` inside of a `<p>` it doesn't work, lol. You just did the same thing again.  If you have a `<p>` inside of a `<p>`, it's not going to work.  If you use a `<div>` or a `<th:block>` as a container it will work.